# Removing <div id="page" class="hfeed"> from wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to create a page which is an exact copy of my index.php page. I have duplicated index.php and renamed it page-newindex.php and included

```
/*
Template Name: homepage
*/
```

at the top of the page so I can select it as a template when creating a new page.

The problem occurs when the page is rendered. Becuase it is a 'page', a containing div which looks like this: `<div id="page" class="hfeed">`  in included which all of the other html is inserted into. This is causing major formatting problems.

How do I get rid of this containing div??

Comment: Edit `page.php`, or `single.php`?

Answer (score 2):

`<div id="page" class="hfeed">` this is added in `header.php`.

If you remove it from `header.php` then it will affect all the pages. So create a custom header for homepage template.

1. Copy `header.php` and paste in a new php file & name it as `header-home.php`
2. In the `header-home.php`, remove `page` id and `hfeed` class from div. ie just keep `<div>`.
3. In homepage template, instead of `get_header()` call `get_header('home');`

With this you have a separate header from which you can remove page id from div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this has not fixed my problem. It turns out that <div id="page"> also appears on the homepage so I dont need to remove it.  Do you know how I can duplicate my index page and make it a template for a page?